# Saving/Loading an ObservableList and an integer as XML

Tags: java, xml, javafx, jaxb

im currently trying to save an ObservableList and an double variable as an XML document. Somehow saving is unsorted(variables are not sorted as they got declared) and loading doesnt work at all.

First of all my ObservableList contains 6  "Week" Objects.
Week Class :

```
public class Week {
    double Montag;
    double Dienstag;
    double Mittwoch;
    double Donnerstag;
    double Freitag;
    double Samstag;
    double Sonntag;
    public Week(double montag, double dienstag, double mittwoch, double donnerstag, double freitag, double samstag,
            double sonntag) {
        Montag = montag;
        Dienstag = dienstag;
        Mittwoch = mittwoch;
        Donnerstag = donnerstag;
        Freitag = freitag;
        Samstag = samstag;
        Sonntag = sonntag;
    }
    public double getMontag() {
        return Montag;
    }
    public void setMontag(double montag) {
        Montag = montag;
    }
    public double getDienstag() {
        return Dienstag;
    }
    public void setDienstag(double dienstag) {
        Dienstag = dienstag;
    }
    public double getMittwoch() {
        return Mittwoch;
    }
    public void setMittwoch(double mittwoch) {
        Mittwoch = mittwoch;
    }
    public double getDonnerstag() {
        return Donnerstag;
    }
    public void setDonnerstag(double donnerstag) {
        Donnerstag = donnerstag;
    }
    public double getFreitag() {
        return Freitag;
    }
    public void setFreitag(double freitag) {
        Freitag = freitag;
    }
    public double getSamstag() {
        return Samstag;
    }
    public void setSamstag(double samstag) {
        Samstag = samstag;
    }
    public double getSonntag() {
        return Sonntag;
    }
    public void setSonntag(double sonntag) {
        Sonntag = sonntag;
    }
}
```

I´ve made a static Method which will return the XML string.
Calling the Method would look like that.

```
String xmlTest = XmlUtils.saveListAsXML(fxTable.getItems(),Double.parseDouble(fxWeek.getText()));
```

fxTable.getItems() will return the ObservableList with 6 "Week"Objects and the other paramter is just an double.
I thought about creating another Class "Weeks" which will contain a double variable and a List of the type "week" and then just serialize the Weeks class. Somehow it doesnt work as i thought?

```
public static String saveListAsXML(ObservableList<Week> list, double Kalenderwoche) {
    Weeks xmlObj = new Weeks();
    xmlObj.setKalender(Kalenderwoche);
    for (Week w : list) {
        xmlObj.addToList(w);
    }
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JAXB.marshal(xmlObj, sw);
    String xmlString = sw.toString();
    return xmlString;
}
```

Weeks Class:

```
package Model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class Weeks {
    @XmlElement
    private double Kalenderwoche;
    @XmlElement
    ArrayList<Week> woche= new ArrayList<>();
    public void addToList(Week week) {  
        woche.add(week);
    System.out.println(week.Dienstag);
    }
    public void setKalender(double wert) {
        Kalenderwoche = wert;
    }
}
```

The Export result looks like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<weeks>
    <Kalenderwoche>12.0</Kalenderwoche>
    <woche>
        <dienstag>0.0</dienstag>
        <donnerstag>0.0</donnerstag>
        <freitag>0.0</freitag>
        <mittwoch>0.0</mittwoch>
        <montag>50.0</montag>
        <samstag>0.0</samstag>
        <sonntag>0.0</sonntag>
    </woche>
    <woche>
        <dienstag>0.0</dienstag>
        <donnerstag>0.0</donnerstag>
        <freitag>0.0</freitag>
        <mittwoch>0.0</mittwoch>
        <montag>0.0</montag>
        <samstag>0.0</samstag>
        <sonntag>0.0</sonntag>
    </woche>
    <woche>
        <dienstag>0.0</dienstag>
        <donnerstag>0.0</donnerstag>
        <freitag>0.0</freitag>
        <mittwoch>0.0</mittwoch>
        <montag>0.0</montag>
        <samstag>0.0</samstag>
        <sonntag>0.0</sonntag>
    </woche>
    <woche>
        <dienstag>0.0</dienstag>
        <donnerstag>0.0</donnerstag>
        <freitag>0.0</freitag>
        <mittwoch>0.0</mittwoch>
        <montag>0.0</montag>
        <samstag>0.0</samstag>
        <sonntag>0.0</sonntag>
    </woche>
    <woche>
        <dienstag>0.0</dienstag>
        <donnerstag>0.0</donnerstag>
        <freitag>0.0</freitag>
        <mittwoch>0.0</mittwoch>
        <montag>0.0</montag>
        <samstag>0.0</samstag>
        <sonntag>0.0</sonntag>
    </woche>
    <woche>
        <dienstag>0.0</dienstag>
        <donnerstag>0.0</donnerstag>
        <freitag>0.0</freitag>
        <mittwoch>0.0</mittwoch>
        <montag>0.0</montag>
        <samstag>0.0</samstag>
        <sonntag>0.0</sonntag>
    </woche>
```

(Note the structure is actually fine and the 0.0 values are right aswell in this case. The only thing that bothers me is that the "woche" section is sorted like that : `dienstag,donnerstag,freitag,mittwoch,montag,samstag,sonntag` and not sorted like in the week object `montag,dienstag,mittwoch,donnerstag,freitag,samstag,sonntag`

I have also created a static method that should load the xml file and create a Weeks Object out of it.
The Method looks like this :

```
public static ObservableList<Week> getXmlAsList(File file) {
         try {

                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Weeks.class);

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                Weeks customer = (Weeks) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

              } catch (JAXBException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
        ObservableList<Week> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        return list;
    }
```

The Method atm will just create an Weeks object and returns an empty list but creating the Weeks object doesnt work at all.

```
Jun 25, 2018 2:21:39 PM com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory create0
INFORMATION: No default constructor found on class Model.Week
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Model.Week.<init>()
```

Im a bit confused about the XML bind, could someone give me a hint or tell me what im doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, add the default constructor: `public Week() {};` ...

Answer (score 1):

Jaxb requires you to provide a constructor that does not take parameters. You need to add such a constructor to `Week`:

```
public Week() {
    this(0d, 0d, 0d, 0d, 0d, 0d, 0d);
}
```

To specify the order of the properties for `Week` using `@XmlType.propOrder`

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"montag", "dienstag", "mittwoch", "donnerstag", "freitag", "samstag", "sonntag"})
public class Week {
```

Furthermore imho you should notify the user of unsuccessfull parsing of the xml instead of just returning the empty list. (You should not return the empty list in all cases anyway.)

```
public static ObservableList<Week> getXmlAsList(File file) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Weeks.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Weeks customer = (Weeks) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(customer.woche);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```